# Qt Designer in Windows along with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, windows-xp

In Linux, I had got Qt Designer installed along with Qt Creator. I had installed Qt Creator in Windows, but I am not able to find the Qt Designer anywhere. Also, I cannot build Qt applications using Qt Creator. I would like to know whether I need to install Qt SDK in windows to get Qt Designer.

Comment: Qt Designer is not a standalone program anymore, it's a feature of Qt Creator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the full bundle:

http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.0/5.0.2/qt-windows-opensource-5.0.2-mingw47_32-x86-offline.exe

For what I remember, QtCreator includes the designer somehow, and it is a cool program to use!

Answer (score 0):

Qt-Designer is part of the "PyQt4"-Package for Windows.